# How to disable right click in embedded video in Scorm file?

Tags: javascript, scorm

I am making a scorm video file. And I want to block download video from student by disabling right click constain Save video as.... But when I use disable function, I only disable right click from index page, this function is not effect to video is embedded on index as below. I use  tag of HTML5 to up video.
[image]

Anyone can help me give a solution to effect in embedded video? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Einz Did you find the answer for this question?